# Is there any element of order 30 in $GL _{10}(\mathbb{C})$ with INTEGER coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra

I can easily find an element of order 30 in $GL _{10}(\mathbb{C})$ as $\begin{pmatrix} \cos\frac{2π}{30} & \sin\frac{π}{15} & 0 \\ \sin\frac{-π}{15} & \cos\frac{π}{15} & 0  \\  0 & 0 & I_8  \end{pmatrix}$  but I want if there is any element of this order with integer coefficients.

Comment: There is even an element of order $120$ in $GL_{10}(\Bbb Z)$, i.e., with integer coefficients, and this is the maximal possible order, see [here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/JofAlgebra98.pdf).

Comment: Please explain how that element can be constructed.

Answer (score 5):

An example: $\begin{bmatrix}A&0&0\\0&B&0\\0&0&C\end{bmatrix}$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$, and $C=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

The blocks have order $2,3,5$ respectively, so when we combine them...

Answer (score 1):

The 30th cyclotomic polynomial is $\Phi_{30}(x) = x^8 + x^7 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1$ and so its companion matrix can be realized as an $8 \times 8$ block in a $10 \times 10$ block diagonal matrix, the other block being the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.